# Change None to Float in List of Strings (Python)

Tags: python, list, replace, nonetype

I have a long list of strings in the following format:

```
    [...
    (0.5, 'house', 'flower'),
    (0.213, 'garden', 'flowerpot'),
    (None, 'mulch', 'hunting'),
    (0.9, 'flower', 'tulip'),
    (0.34, 'party', 'music'),
    (None, 'piano', 'trowel'),
    (0.138, 'fertilizer', 'cow')
    ...]
```

And before I can sort the list based on the first element, I have to convert the None types to floats. How do I change all the Nones in the list to float 0?

I am trying:

```
mylist = map(lambda x: 0 if x[0] == None, else x, mylist)
```

But somewhere I am going wrong with the syntax - anyone have advice for a Pythonic replace all on Nones in the first element of each string for the whole list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
list(map(lambda x: (0.0,)+x[1:] if x[0] is None else x,mylist))
```

which produces:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: (0.0,)+x[1:] if x[0] is None else x,mylist))
[(0.5, 'house', 'flower'), (0.213, 'garden', 'flowerpot'), (0.0, 'mulch', 'hunting'), (0.9, 'flower', 'tulip'), (0.34, 'party', 'music'), (0.0, 'piano', 'trowel'), (0.138, 'fertilizer', 'cow')]
```

The code works as follows: we thus perform a mapping with `lambda x: (0.0,)+x[1:] if x[0] is None else x` as mapping function.

This is a *ternary operator*: if the first element `x[0] is None`, we return `(0.0,)+x[1:]` so we construct a new tuple with `0.0` as first element, and `x[1:]` as remaining elements. If the first element is not `None`, we simply return `x`.

This will work for every tuple, given it has *at least one element*. If there can be empty tuples in the list, we can alter the expression to:

```
list(map(lambda x: (0.0,)+x[1:] if x and x[0] is None else x,mylist))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
l = [(0.5, 'house', 'flower'),
    (0.213, 'garden', 'flowerpot'),
    (None, 'mulch', 'hunting'),
    (0.9, 'flower', 'tulip'),
    (0.34, 'party', 'music'),
    (None, 'piano', 'trowel'),
    (0.138, 'fertilizer', 'cow'),
]

l = [ (0.0,)+ x[1:] if x[0] is None else x  for x in l]
```

The output:

```
[(0.5, 'house', 'flower'), (0.213, 'garden', 'flowerpot'), (0.0, 'mulch', 'hunting'), (0.9, 'flower', 'tulip'), (0.34, 'party', 'music'), (0.0, 'piano', 'trowel'), (0.138, 'fertilizer', 'cow')]
```